# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'SolutionArchitectID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, html-helper

Not sure if the drop down I created is sending a selected value. Am I missing an argument from DropDownList helper?

**CreateDropDowns method**

```
List<SelectListItem> EmployeeList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (Employee e in db.Employees)
        {
            EmployeeList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName, Value = e.SolutionArchitectID.ToString() });
        }

ViewBag.EmployeeList = EmployeeList;
```

**UpdateDetails method**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult UpdateDetails(int SolutionArchitectID) {

Asset currAppRecord = db.Assets.Where(a => a.ApplicationID == ApplicationID).Single();
...
currAppRecord.SolutionArchitectID = SolutionArchitectID;
...
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateDetails", "Atlas"))
{
 ...
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Employees">Solution Architect</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("EmployeeList")
            </div>
        </div>
...
}
```

SolutionArchitectID is the field to update in the db table on submit.

Comment: I guess, problem is with your action method parameter which is receiving null/empty string. Try sending some integer value for that parameter in url and try again. Or you can make parameter type as `string` and parse it inside controller to handle.

Comment: If I remove the SolutionArchitectID argument from the update method in the controller, the form update goes through fine, that's what makes me think I must be using the wrong overload for the DropDownList helper.

Comment: I think you need to post some sample code showing the flow you are doing from View to controller (e.g: with action method signature and correct markup you use etc.)

Comment: Edited. Included more of the view, and the update method that is called when the form is submitted.

Comment: Ok. What are the value type in dropdown are they numbers or text? Try with `@Html.DropDownList("SolutionArchitectID")` and see if that bind value in controller. If dropdown `value` are text then try changing controller signature to: `public ActionResult UpdateDetails(string SolutionArchitectID) {`

Comment: You need to show your GET method.

Answer (score 0):

In your `using` there is no Html control with name SolutionArchitectID. For your form to be submitted successfully you will need to pass SolutionArchitectID. As shown in below code.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateDetails", "Atlas"))
{
 ...
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Employees">Solution Architect</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("EmployeeList")
                @Html.Hidden("SolutionArchitectID", <<PutHereSomeValue>>)   
            </div>
        </div>
...
}
```

I think answers to below questions will help more

- How will you get value for SolutionArchitectID?
- Whether it will be send back with form or not?

Comment: SolutionArchitectID is the field to update in the db table on submit. Added to the original post for clarity.

Comment: Please post your Form tag along with controller method to help you better.

Comment: Edited. Included the form in the view, and the update method that is called when the form is submitted